# Using an ODBC connection in Access get retrieve data from DB2

Tags: ms-access, db2, odbc

Using Access 2010, I have set up an ODBC link to my organizations DB2 Database. From this database, I'm getting several tables, one of which houses over 100k records, on any given day, there may be 10 records added. I'm trying to find a way to restrict the data pool from this one table to just new records. Does anybody know of a good starting point for this?

Comment: Does that table have a column that contains Date Added? If so, just use a query to select rows with the current date. You could create a query that sorts descending on your key field (if like an AutoNumber) than tell it to take the TOP 20 or 30 or ... however that to me is a bad idea due to the performance.

Comment: Wayne, it does have a timestamp field. but I'd still have to pull in all the records to run the query. I'm looking for a way that I can have Access pass the statement to DB2 and only retrieve the new records.

Comment: You didn't mention if you plan to update the records locally or just view them. I have not worked with DB2 in many years, but I assume it will support 'Pass-Through' queries? If so, the 'Sort/Top' will all run on your server and not on the local machine, thus no performance hit.

Comment: the way the connection, they can't be updated, only viewed. Even if I link the table, the data comes back as #deleted.  I think that limits me further.

Comment: I believe the #Deleted is caused by a field in DB2 defined as BigInt? If you read a ways down in this link http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/182933-linked-db2-table-msaccess-2000-shows-deleted-every-record you will see their suggestion to fix that.  You still don't mention if you need to update the records, so I am assuming read-only.  Or look here: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/713548-linked-db2-table-records-showing-up-deleted

Answer (score 0):

Have the DBA create a view that contains only the records you are interested in, then attach that just like a table. If you do a filter on the Access side of the equation, you will still be pulling the entire table down over the wire.